# php count() didn't work for object

Tags: php

i have object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
        )

)
```

The count() function should show 2 but it is showing 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope it work

```
$count = count((array)$obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/count):

> For objects, if you have [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.spl.php) installed, you can hook into `count()` by implementing interface [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php). The interface has exactly one method, [`Countable::count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php), which returns the return value for the `count()` function.

`stdClass` does *not* `implements Countable`, therefore `count` will simply return `1`.

> If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented `Countable` interface, `1` will be returned.

(In other words, RTM :p)

Answer (score 0):

`count()` counts the indexes in an array, not the properties on an object. Try casting the object as an array by using

```
count((array)$objectName);
```

From documentation,

> count() Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Comment: Off topic: "`count()` counts the indexes in an array, not the properties on an object.` " Given the way PHP sometimes work, I would not be surprised if `count(<object>)` actually returned the number of properties.